# How to display razor and html code snippets in razor view

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am creating a site with custom components where I need to display the Html and Razor code snippets for the components so they can be copied by others.

For example if the component in the view is the following:

```
<div class="k-content">
     @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                    .Name("datepicker")
                    .Value("05/12/2018")
    )
</div>
```

I want to be able to display exactly how it is coded in the view, so the view would look the same. That way someone can see the code, and copy and paste it on the view.

I have tried using pre tags but that does not work. The only way I was able to do it was to use a tool to encode the < tags and > tags. See below:

```
<pre>
    &lt;div class="k-content"&gt;
        &nbsp;&#x40;(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
        .Name("datepicker")
        .Value("05/12/2018"))
    &lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: Are you want to show HTML tags and Razor codes from user input to a  div element? If I'm right, then you need `Html.Raw()` to show the content as-is with unencoded strings, or use `<code>` tag.

Comment: I want to show the Html and razor code as it is shown in code - so someone can copy and paste the code and put it into their own view.